# Is "dominant in microsoft office" correct?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm filling a resume and i want to say that I am good in word,excel and powerpoint.
is saying "dominant in microsoft office" or " dominant in microsoft word and excel" correct?

Comment: Use _proficient_ as suggested. Don't mention the whole of MS Office if you only know your way around those three parts of it; the office suite also contains Outlook, OneNote, Access and more. Also, don't boast about being _very_ good in it unless you actually are able to use the power-user functions such as, _programming_ in the underlying VBa, connecting the different parts of the suite with external (data) sources and creating actual applications based on the existing software... If you can write a letter, create a spreadsheet and make a presentation, _proficient_ is the word :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct word would be *proficient*. *Dominant* would mean that you're more powerful than other people, or that you are influential in its design.

Answer (score 0):

if you are really excellent, you can use ***proficient***. If not that much, you can use ***familiar with*** or ***aware of***

Answer (score -1):

The both sentences making sense that you are commanding/ruling the application of MS office so better you can prefer "I'm quite capable of using MS office".